# Send SVG behing border div

Tags: css

I am making an infography, and I want to place a round circle with a border behind the border line of a div, as show in this picture:

[image: Resul wanted]

As you can see in the image, the circle is behind the path in the layers. I have tried with z-index and I can not make it work. The result I have right now is perfect but for the fact that I can not place the circle behind:

[image]

```css
.flex {
  display: flex !important;
}

.contenido {
  height: 180px;
}

.left {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.up {
  border-top: 5px solid;
  border-color: #5396C3;
}

.color {
  border-color: #5396C3;
}

.left-half {
  width: 16.667%;
}

.right-half {
  width: 16.667%;
}

.d {
  border-top-right-radius: 500px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 500px;
  border-right: 5px solid;
  border-color: #5396C3;
  z-index: 8;
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.down {
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-color: #5396C3;
}


/* This is the point that need to be behind */

.right-point {
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 62px;
  margin-right: -23px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex contenido">
  <div class="left up color">
  </div>
  <div class="left-half up color">
  </div>
  <div class="right-half up down d color">
    <img src="svg/work.svg" alt="" class="right-point">
  </div>
  <div class="right color">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex contenido">
  <div class="left ">
    <div class="flex" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
      <img src="img/vv.png" alt="" class="logo logo-left ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-half up down c work" style="margin-top: -5px;">
    <img src="svg/work.svg" alt="" class="left-point">
  </div>
  <div class="right-half color">
  </div>
  <div class="right color">
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is the circle not going behind the border?
In my case I am using an SVG as a circle, maybe it is a better idea to create the circle with CSS (does it even affect the fact that is an SVG?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the z-index and position relative from class .d and add position relative for the .right-point

```css
.flex {
  display: flex !important;
}

.contenido {
  height: 180px;
}

.left {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.up {
  border-top: 5px solid;
  border-color: #5396C3;
}

.color {
  border-color: #5396C3;
}

.left-half {
  width: 16.667%;
}

.right-half {
  width: 16.667%;
}

.d {
  border-top-right-radius: 500px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 500px;
  border-right: 5px solid;
  border-color: #5396C3;
 
  
}

.right {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.down {
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-color: #5396C3;
}


/* This is the point that need to be behind */

.right-point {
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 62px;
  margin-right: -23px;
  z-index: -1;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex contenido">
  <div class="left up color">
  </div>
  <div class="left-half up color">
  </div>
  <div class="right-half up down d color">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Yin_yang.svg/1024px-Yin_yang.svg.png" alt="" class="right-point">
  </div>
  <div class="right color">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex contenido">
  <div class="left ">
    <div class="flex" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
      <img src="img/vv.png" alt="" class="logo logo-left ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-half up down c work" style="margin-top: -5px;">
    <img src="svg/work.svg" alt="" class="left-point">
  </div>
  <div class="right-half color">
  </div>
  <div class="right color">
  </div>
</div>
```